# mysql comparing two integers from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

```
if($num>0) {
    echo "<table border=2> Table Request".$_SESSION['s1'];
    echo"<tr>
        <td>Id</td><td>Drug</td><td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>";
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $r[$i]=$row[1];
        echo "<tr>";
        for($j=0;$j<$num1;$j++) {
            echo"<td>$row[$j]</td>";
        }
        echo"<td><input type='Checkbox' name='p[$i]'  value='on' unchecked /></td>";
        echo"<td><input type='txt' name='q[$i]' /></td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        $r[$i]=$row[1];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['p'])) {
        foreach($_POST['p'] as $key=>$value) {
            if($value == "on") {
                $query8 = "select $r[$i] from $_SESSION['t'] ";
                echo $query8;
                $result8 = mysql_query($query8);
                $num8=Mysql_num_rows($result8);
                if($num8!=0) {
                    $query7="select qun from $_SESSION['t']";
                    $result7 = mysql_query($query8);
                    //?????????????????
                }
            }
            echo"</table>";
        }
    }//result
}//else
```

I have a table request and another table for example E.

I want to compare the field quantity of these tables

```
if(select qun from request)<((select qun from $_SESSION['t'])) // some work
```

How can I write this code in the part that I marked with many question marks?
is this correct?

Comment: Why don't you indent your code properly? Right now it's hard to read for everyone, including you.

Comment: please edit your code, and only add the important par, having too much code drive people away from answering your question

Comment: what do you mean? how can i write it to making understand all?

Comment: Can you remove all the irrelevant code and ask a clearer question?

Comment: when the table will be checked it must compare the quantity of the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want what the title says, why you don't do something like that

```
SELECT table1.quantity AS qu1, table2.quantity AS qu2 FROM table1, table2 WHERE your_conditions;
```

When you get the results, you can compare qu1 against qu2.

But if you are looking for something different, than please be more specific with your question.

Actual example:

```
$query8 = 'SELECT '.$_SESSION[ 't'].'.'.$r[$i].' AS qu1, request.qun AS qu2 FROM '.$_SESSION[ 't'].', request';
$result8 = mysql_query($query8);
while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_array($result8)) {
    if ($row8[ 'qu1'] < $row8[ 'qu2']) {
        echo 'the value from '.$r[$i]. ' is smaller';
    } elseif ($row8[ 'qu1'] > $row8[ 'qu2']) {
        echo 'the value from '.$r[$i]. ' is bigger';
    } else {
        echo 'both values are same';
    }
}
```

Comment: when i select them it will result on the tables yes? i want to catch them and compare them

Comment: You mean i can write this? $q="select t1.qun  as q1"; what will be the value of $q? it is just a string not that integer my problem is this.

Comment: how i can catch the value integer from table of my sql and store it in a variable?

Comment: check my updated post. place that code after `if($value == "on") {` and remove your current one.

Comment: it has error maybe my code from previous is not correct i'm trying to use your code in another page i think you are right thank you